# Returning multiple columns

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi All newbie here in Neo4J,
I am trying to return keys or properties using the following simple query  in the neo4J broswer environment.

```
MATCH (n:movies),(m:people)
RETURN properties(n,m)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to return the properties for both the movies and people nodes
However, I would always get an error

```
Too many parameters for function 'properties' (line 2, column 9 (offset: 36))
" RETURN properties(n,m)"
```

I have tried,

```
MATCH (n:movies),(m:people)
RETURN properties(k) in [n,m]
```

The error I would get

```
Variable `k` not defined (line 2, column 20 (offset: 47))
" RETURN properties(k) in [n,m]"
```

I am trying to pass a list here into k but NEO4J is not permitting me to do so. Is it even possible to pass a list into the function properties() ??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [properties function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-properties) takes exactly one node or a relationship as input.

```
MATCH (n:movies),(m:people) RETURN properties(n), properties(m)
```

will create a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).
i.e. If you have five movies and ten people, you will get a result of all 50 combinations.

If you aren't looking for a cartesian product, you would have to define a specific pattern or restrict the MATCH clause further.

If you want just the individual properties without combining them, consider [Union](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/).

```
MATCH (n:Movie)
RETURN properties(n) as `Properties`
UNION ALL
MATCH (m:Person)
RETURN properties(m) as `Properties`
```

Why am I using aliases for a seemingly simple query? To avoid this:

> All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names (line 3,
> column 1 (offset: 39))

For working with lists:
The [collect](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function lets you create/construct a list from the results while [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) expands a list into a sequence of rows.

Answer (score 1):

`properties()` only takes one argument, you can try

```
MATCH (n:movies),(m:people) RETURN properties(n) as prop_n, properties(m) as prop_m
```

or more optimal query would be

```
MATCH (n:movies) optional match (m:people) RETURN properties(n) as prop_n, properties(m) as prop_m
```

> MATCH (n:movies),(m:people)
> RETURN properties(k) in [n,m]

since you have not defined k so you are getting the error. Also according to [doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-properties) properites() takes "An expression that returns a relationship, a node, or a map" as an argument. Your query is not supported.